# AVCaptureMetadataOutput unsupported type found error in XCode

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

Error Log:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:] - unsupported type found.  Use -availableMetadataObjectTypes.'
*** First throw call stack:

This is the availableMetadataObjectTypes in debugger log. I don't understand why this is empty.

(lldb) po [output availableMetadataObjectTypes]
<__NSArrayM 0x810ae990>()

Here is the code
    NSError* error;

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];

AVCaptureDevice* device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

AVCaptureDeviceInput* deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
    [session addInput:deviceInput];
}

previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

CALayer *rootLayer = [[self scannerView] layer];
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[previewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(self.scannerView.frame.origin.x, self.scannerView.frame.origin.y, self.scannerView.frame.size.width, self.scannerView.frame.size.height)];
[rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

_labelBarcode = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, 40)];
_labelBarcode.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
_labelBarcode.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.scannerView addSubview:_labelBarcode];

[self rotatePreviewLayerToDeviceOrientation];

[session startRunning];

AVCaptureMetadataOutput* output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
if ([session canAddOutput:output]) {
    [session addOutput:output];
}
[output availableMetadataObjectTypes];
output.metadataObjectTypes = @[
                               AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                               AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                               AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                               AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                               AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                               AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                               AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code
                               ];
```

}

Comment: Matt, could you please take a look at my code again? This error only happened after I upgrade to iOS 9.

Comment: Matt, you meant this ?   [output availableMetadataObjectTypes]; Could you  please be more specific?

Comment: Thank you Matt for your time, but it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check `availableMetadataObjectTypes`, but if you haven't added an input device, the list will be empty.

The hint comes from a comment on `availableMetadataObjectTypes` in  `AVCaptureOutput.h`:

> Available 
>       metadata object types are dependent on the capabilities of the AVCaptureInputPort to which this receiver's 
>       AVCaptureConnection is connected.

e.g. my back camera supports aztec and code128.

```
NSError *error;
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

// Check input and error here.

[session addInput:input];


AVCaptureMetadataOutput* output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
if ([session canAddOutput:output]) {
    [session addOutput:output];
}

// NOW try adding metadata types
session.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                           AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code];
```